# How do I write a regex that match following text?

Tags: regex

FROM: `START 123 456 789 START abc def ghi START xyz`

I want to get three results:

- `START 123 456 789`
- `START abc def ghi`
- `START xyz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
(START[a-z\s\d]+)
```

which matches START followed by any lowercase letter, digit or space.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/qL4gA0/1)

However, I'm not sure why you are not using a simple split().

Comment: Thank you for your answer, maybe I should be more specific - I actually want to catch all the content between two STARTs but also the content after the last START.

Comment: It does.  Click the demo.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qL4gA0/2 <- I would like to get that </div> into first group as well.

Comment: @Inez, that's a completely different string, and not what was in your question. This is a classic [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), you asked for (and got) help for something that was absolutely not what you needed.  A more useful solution to your problem (which is NOT the same as a good answer to your question) is that you shouldn't try to parse HTML using a regex. Regex is not the language for SGML.  Use something with DOM support instead. PHP, Python, Perl, etc.  [You just can't parse HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1072112)

Comment: @Inez, I recommend you give ergonaut the green checkmark for accurately answering your question, then move on to a better question that includes source code of your actual attempt to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve.